# Stagnation points (Body vs Tube)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, drag, flow

Can anyone please help me understand the stagnation points? If we look at the comparison between the flow of air over a wing and flow in a pitot tube, the theory says that the velocity is 0 (or very close to 0) for both cases. Having a stream hitting the wing, all the kinetic energy goes into internal energy. This is very intuitive! But why is the velocity considered 0 at the entrance of a pitot tube? It's very counterintuitive for me...

[image]

Can anyone help me to understand this? How can that velocity be 0 at the entrance of the pitot tube? This issues's been following me for days.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From what I read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot_tube) (sorry, I'm not an expert), air doesn't flow through the tube. So its velocity is 0.

> ... the moving fluid is brought to rest (stagnates) as there is no outlet to allow flow to continue

Comment: Darn! I always though they are opened to ambient because of those two orifices for static pressure... Now it makes more sense. So the hole fills with air and acts as a solid body, right? Is this a correct interpretation?